# apache 2 + centos 6 + php 5.3.3. - Segmentation fault (11) - tsrm_realpath_r

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, joomla

we have problem with many JOOMLA sites on our servers.

Error is only Segm. fault 11. In browser is "no data". After debug trace I have this.

```
¨Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/httpd'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f6985296721 in tsrm_realpath_r (path=0x7ffff2bab270 "/www/domain.cz/domain.cz/language/cs-CZ/cs-CZ.xml", start=1, len=53, ll=0x7ffff2bab26c, t=0x7ffff2bab260,
    use_realpath=1, is_dir=1, link_is_dir=0x0) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.3.3/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.c:609
609     {
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
(gdb)  print (char *)executor_globals.active_op_array->function_name
$2 = 0x7f699711e3d0 "getMetadata"
(gdb) print (char *)executor_globals.active_op_array->filename
$3 = 0x7f6997088da8 "/www/domain.cz/domain.cz/libraries/joomla/language/language.php"
```

Can you help me please, where can be problem?

Thank you Pavel

Comment: Is debug mode enabled in Joomla?

Comment: Yes, but without effect. Browser show "no data response". Error log with E_ALL contain Segm. fault only.

Comment: One new - I found this [Fri Jan 24 13:00:43 2014] [error] [client ] PHP Warning: is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/minify_2be10eb8b772bfd4bd1468d906a5c3fa.gz) is not within the allowed path(s): (/www/autoprep:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/www/x.cz:/var/www/web‌​5/x.cz:/var/www/web2/x.cz) in /www/x.cz/x.cz/plugins/system/shadowbox/shadowbox/min/li‌​b/Minify/Cache/File.php on line 33, referer: x.cz/index.php/zajimavosti-o-zbozi ........but clients have acces only to private tmp in document root dir.

Comment: Fix tmp path of minify is not solution for this problem :(

Comment: What happens if you disable debug mode?

Comment: Same situation. But when i disable zend-guard, zend-opcache and ioncube, so i get this Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to  allocate 523800 bytes) in  /www/x.cz/x.cz/libraries/joomla/language/language.php  on line 1169 ... but when i set e.g. 256M so problem is again. But only for some reload of page. One time is all ok, next time is NO DATA or this after disable modules in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have it!

So, problem is with Piwik. As is described here:

http://dev.piwik.org/trac/ticket/4409#ticket

In one version was used  libxml_disable_entity_loader() - this fce. is not thread safe. So this do faults of JOOMLA sites.